# Calling SetupDiGetClassDevsW function How to enter parameters

Tags: python, ctypes

I am using the SetupDiGetClassDevsW function in Python,But I don't know how to enter the parameters
`Flags = DIGCF_PRESENT`an error will occur `NameError: name 'DIGCF_PRESENT' is not defined`
please what should i do ?

https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/windows/win32/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdigetclassdevsw?redirectedfrom=MSDN

```
import ctypes as ct
from ctypes import wintypes as w

SetupAPI = ct.WinDLL('SetupAPI')

SetupAPI.SetupDiGetClassDevsW.argtypes = w.CHAR,w.PWCHAR,w.HWND,w.DWORD
SetupAPI.SetupDiGetClassDevsW.restype = w.HANDLE

ClassGuid = None
Enumerator = None
hwndParent = None
Flags = DIGCF_PRESENT

Handle = SetupAPI.SetupDiGetClassDevsW(ClassGuid,
                                       Enumerator,
                                       hwndParent,
                                       Flags)
```

**Update - 2**

The updated code is as follows,print `HANDLE` gets `18446744073709551615` is that correct? Expected to get device information.

```
import ctypes as ct
from ctypes import wintypes as w

SetupAPI = ct.WinDLL('SetupAPI')

SetupAPI.SetupDiGetClassDevsW.argtypes w.LPVOID,w.PWCHAR,w.HWND,w.DWORD
SetupAPI.SetupDiGetClassDevsW.restype = w.HANDLE

DIGCF_DEFAULT         =  0x00000001  
DIGCF_PRESENT         =  0x00000002
DIGCF_ALLCLASSES      =  0x00000004
DIGCF_PROFILE         =  0x00000008
DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE =  0x00000010

ClassGuid = None
Enumerator = None
hwndParent = None
Flags = DIGCF_PRESENT

Handle = SetupAPI.SetupDiGetClassDevsW(ClassGuid,
                                       Enumerator,
                                       hwndParent,
                                       Flags)
print(Handle)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in SetupApi.h:

```c
//
// Flags controlling what is included in the device information set built
// by SetupDiGetClassDevs
//
#define DIGCF_DEFAULT           0x00000001  // only valid with DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE
#define DIGCF_PRESENT           0x00000002
#define DIGCF_ALLCLASSES        0x00000004
#define DIGCF_PROFILE           0x00000008
#define DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE   0x00000010
```

Then you can define the constants in Python:

```py
DIGCF_DEFAULT         =  0x00000001  # only valid with DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE
DIGCF_PRESENT         =  0x00000002
DIGCF_ALLCLASSES      =  0x00000004
DIGCF_PROFILE         =  0x00000008
DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE =  0x00000010
```

Also note that the first parameter to `SetupDiGetClassDevsW` is a `GUID*`, not a `CHAR`, so `.argtypes` should be at a minimum `w.LPVOID` if you are only passing `None`.

Also look at the [examples in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdigetclassdevsw#examples).  Below returns a valid handle:

```py
import ctypes as ct
from ctypes import wintypes as w

SetupAPI = ct.WinDLL('SetupAPI')

SetupAPI.SetupDiGetClassDevsW.argtypes = w.LPVOID,w.PWCHAR,w.HWND,w.DWORD
SetupAPI.SetupDiGetClassDevsW.restype = w.HANDLE

DIGCF_DEFAULT         =  0x00000001  
DIGCF_PRESENT         =  0x00000002
DIGCF_ALLCLASSES      =  0x00000004
DIGCF_PROFILE         =  0x00000008
DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE =  0x00000010

ClassGuid = None
Enumerator = None
hwndParent = None
Flags = DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_ALLCLASSES

Handle = SetupAPI.SetupDiGetClassDevsW(ClassGuid,
                                       Enumerator,
                                       hwndParent,
                                       Flags)
print(hex(Handle))
```

Output:

```
0x1e4258bcb50
```

Comment: updated code is as follows,print HANDLE gets 18446744073709551615 is that correct?

Comment: No that’s INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE. Use DIGCF_PRESENT

Comment: I modified the code , gets `18446744073709551615` what should i do ?

Comment: @user19212551 See my update for working code.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand very well, why is it HEX instead of device list

Comment: @user19212551  It only returns a handle.  `hex()` just makes it easy to read. 0xffffffffffffffff is the `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` value.  If it is anything else it worked and returned a valid handle.  See [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/43ab4902-75b9-4c5c-9b54-4567c825539f/how-to-enumerate-hardware-devices-by-using-setupdi?forum=vcgeneral) for everything else you have to do to get a device list.

Comment: It turns out that I thought that I can get the device information in this way, it is a bit difficult to convert c to python

Comment: `SP_DEVINFO_DATA` structure how  to use this on python

Comment: Use `ctypes.Structure`.  This question is answered.  Please upvote/accept this one and ask a new one if you have new issues.

Comment: Okay ! Got it !!